# Remove link and add class based on date

Tags: jquery

I have a calendar built with html and php, and I have the following format for listing the month links:

```
    <ul class="month-list">
        <li class="nolink">Jan</li>
        <li class="nolink">Feb</li>
        <li class="nolink">Mar</li>
        <li><a href="?month=April">Apr</a></li>
        <li><a href="?month=May">May</a></li>
        <li><a href="?month=June">Jun</a></li>
        <li><a href="?month=July">Jul</a></li>
        <li><a href="?month=August">Aug</a></li>
        <li><a href="?month=September">Sep</a></li>
        <li><a href="?month=October">Oct</a></li>
        <li><a href="?month=November">Nov</a></li>
        <li><a href="?month=December">Dec</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I need to do date comparison with jQuery to remove the link if the month is past, and add the class of nolink, but was unable to find the correct syntax.

I am looking for syntax that essentially does this:
if Month = Current Month, remove links from previous months and add class "nolink"

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `:lt()` jQuery selector and JS's `new Date().getMonth()` it's easy:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/igukuy/6/edit)**</kbd>

```
var m = new Date().getMonth(); // Returns the curr. month "zero" based (0 -> 11)

$('.month-list li:lt('+ m +')').each(function(){
  $('a', this).contents().unwrap('a').parent('li').addClass('nolink');
});
```

To test it with all months instead of `var m = new Date().getMonth();` put manually values from `0` to `11` in the demo. It will be a bit tricky but just consider the current month is `a value -1`

Answer (score 0):

Is it also possible to connect days in this code example? I am trying to delete agenda items as soon as the day in the month is past. I have it working now on months, thanks to this post, but i have to connect it now to the day in that month, to get it deleted, after the day has passed.

For example:
I have 3 agenda items. One on July 26th, one on July 29th and one on August 2nd.

It's now July 31st, so i want the first two agenda items automatically deleted.

For example you'll get:

```
 <ul class="month-list">
    <li><a href="?day=26?month=July">Event 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?day=29?month=July">Event 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="?day=2?month=August">Event 3</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
var d = new Date(),
m = d.getMonth(), 
day = d.getDay();

$('.month-list li:lt('+ m +')').each(function(){
$('a', this).contents().unwrap('a').parent('li').addClass('nolink');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Further questions should either be posed as comments to an actual answer or as new question themselves.  As it stands, this answer is _not_ an answer but a question